# VLC won't display AVI via PuTTY: 'xcb vout display error: X server failure' error produced

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc, xserver, putty

I'm producing `AVI` files from `OpenCV` (on Ubuntu 16.04) - which I'd like to watch.

Thus, I installed `VLC` using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
sudo apt-get install  libav-tools
```

However, when trying to watch the AVIs via PuTTY, both my created `AVI` videos, and `AVI` videos downloaded from the www, repeatedly display the following error: `xcb vout display error: X server failure` (I'm able to watch the www downloaded `AVIs` on the console).

**1. Any way to get `VLC` to display `AVI` files on Ubuntu with PuTTY?

 2. If not, any recommended alternative to `VLC` for video display on via PuTTY?**

[image]

Comment: Putty is a terminal emulator, you can't watch video there.

Comment: @Pilot6, PuTTY is able to interact with my XServer - to display graphic content (e.g., xclock): video should be possible.

Comment: +1 I am having the same problem. @boardrider , did you manage to fix it?

Comment: If I recall. @iyop45, the problem was solved: alas, I don't remember the solution's details.

Comment: Ah, no worries. I have found that I can use the camera fine with OpenCV instead of VLC, which will do for now.